# Implement a WCF-Mock and the endpoint before implementing the real service

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5

**Background:**

I have to extend an application which already uses WCF services with another WCF Service. One of these already existing services should call the new WCF service. Now the requirements are that the future service should be mocked and the connection between this two services should be tested (not a unit test) with this mock service before implementing the real service. The mock service should write the received parameters to a file.

**Goal:**

This means the endpoint in the existing WCF service is implemented and ready (except for some changes in the config).

**My approaches:**

Implement own mock service ([Blog post](http://bronumski.blogspot.ch/2011/09/hosting-mock-as-wcf-service.html)) or use a mock framework ([WCFMock](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/)) which mocks a already defined interface.

**Problems:**

The call of the mock service looks different and I have to change the code of the endpoint after the implementation of the real service.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to mock or fake a WCF service (without real web call) and implement the endpoint which will also work with the real WCF service after changing the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will need to create a class that acts as an intermediary for the WCF service client calls and then either loads an actual client or your mock service depending on some value (probably a config value). This way, the dependencies in your code are handled such that all you need to do is change a flag in order to switch implementations.

The biggest constraint on this working is that the service interface must be available to the client to implement.

Basic idea is as follows:

```
public class ServiceFacade : IMyWCFService
{
    private IMyWCFService _clientImplementation;

    public ServiceFacade()
    {
        _clientImplementation = (Settings.Default.UseMockService == true) ? new MockWCFServiceClient() : new MyWcfServiceClient();

    }

    #region IMyWCFService implementation

    public int MyServiceCall()
    {
       return _clientImplementation.MyServiceCall();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. It's a nice solution

Comment: No problem. This is also where PRISM's Dependency Injection via configuration comes into it's own as the service class creation and injection is handled by PRISM automagically via the app.config file -something to bear in mind if you are using DI.